# Before Tobi/Madara fought Konan, why no one tried to attack him while he's transporting himself?

Tags: naruto

We now know that Tobi 'materialized' when he's transporting himself. There were some occasions when he's so close to his enemies while transporting:

- When Tobi/Madara was wrapped by Yamato's wood style. Kakashi, Yamato, and Naruto were there. After finished talking, Tobi's transporting himself. Kakashi was RIGHT BEHIND HIM with Raikiri, but he(Kakashi) didn't at least try to attack him.
- After finished talking about his plan in the Five Kage Summit, he's transporting himself IN FRONT OF THE FIVE KAGE and other people there.

I actually have 2 questions:

1. I understand that they(other people) had tried to attack him for like a million times and failed. But why no one tried to attack him when he's transporting?
2. Why Tobi/Madara was SO CONFIDENT AND CASUAL in transporting himself when his enemies were so close to him?
   I mean yes he could just immediately stop his transportation if someone who's fast enough tried to attack him, but then it would give a change for his *jutsu*'s secret to be revealed.

P.S. I know his real identity, I've finished the series.

Answer (score 4):

**The main reason is simply because they did not know he materialized when he "dissapeared".**  The first time that the [Eight man squad](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Eight_Man_Squad) ran into tobi, Kakashi along with everyone else hypothesized hat he could erase himself from existence. 
[image]

What your missing out is, the only reason why someone would try to attack him during that split time frame is if they understand/discover the secret behind his Jutsu.

It would seem that tobi was adept at screwing around with people, he was a master at manipulation and psychological warfare. That's how we won Sasuke and Nagato over, and almost made Naruto to rethink his perspective. He used a bit of [Classical conditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_conditioning) on his opponents, think about it this way, tobi would usually always stick around until the opponent was worn out from attacking him and missing, at that point, doubts will arise after missing so many times. Trying to hit him while he's warping away would seem to elicit the exact same result. And even thou that was not the actual case, it logically seemed that way. And for a majority of the series it worked for him.